# How do I perform this join query?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a table `leave_form` which looks like:

```
type     id reporting_id leave_bal from_date_id leave_from to_date_id leave_to number leave_for status applied_dates_id pendays
personal 99 6            10        1023         full day   1313       full day 10     personal  yes    1026             null
```

I have separate table for dates, so that I can refer these dates into `leave_form`. My `leave_date` table looks like:

```
date_id(AI)  dates(UK)
1025        2016-02-18
1301        2016-02-20
1218        2016-02-16
```

This `date_id` I have inserted into `from_date_id, to_date_id, applied_dates_id` columns in `leave_form` table i.e. all dates are inserted into `leave_date` table and from this table I am only referring the `date_id` into `leave_form` table.

There is also a table that keeps the `emp_code` and `emp_name`. My `personal` table is:

```
id(AI)  emp_code(PK)   emp_name
99        K0209         Nijo
```

When I am trying to fetch the date for `from_date_id, to_date_id, applied_dates_id` column from `leave_form` table I don't get any values.

My query for fetching the dates is:

```
select g.type, a.emp_code, h.rm_id, h.rm_name, g.leave_bal, i1.dates as from_date,
    g.leave_from, i2.dates as to_date, g.leave_to, g.number, g.leave_for, g.status,
    i3.dates as applied_date, g.pendays
  from personal a
  inner join leave_form g
    on a.id = g.id
  inner join inform_to_rm h
    on h.reporting_id = g.reporting_id
  inner join leave_dates i1
    on i1.dates = g.from_date_id
  inner join leave_dates i2
    on i2.dates = g.to_date_id
  inner join leave_dates i3
    on i3.dates = g.applied_dates_id
  where a.emp_code = 'K0209';
```

It shows me result like:

```
type, emp_code, rm_id, rm_name, leave_bal, from_date, leave_from, to_date, leave_to, number, leave_for, status, applied_date, pendays
```

i.e no data gets returned when I am executing this query.

Comment: You will try to left join like "Left join leave_form g". Because inner join only return the result if two tables having matched value otherwise it is nothing return anything

Comment: a side question: why do you use this date_id construct instead of simply having the date in your leave_form table?

Comment: i have done the left join but it is not returning the dates for from_date,to_date,applied_date. i want the dates should be return by comparing the date_id with leave_dates table and leave_form table.

Comment: Is it really the case that each employee can only have one leave_form?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with one of the comments to the question. I would recommend referencing the date directly in the leave_form table instead of a FK to a table with dates. But back to the question. You haven't described all of your tables completely, so it is possible that there are multiple problems that I can't see, however, there is definitely one problem.

Your query joins on

```
inner join leave_dates i1
  on i1.dates = g.from_date_id
inner join leave_dates i2
  on i2.dates = g.to_date_id
inner join leave_dates i3
  on i3.dates = g.applied_dates_id
```

This is incorrect. leave_dates.dates is the actual DATE, while the columns that you are joining on (leave_form.from_date_id, leave_form.to_date_id, leave_form.applied_dates_id) are foreign key references.

For example, 1023 does not equal 2016-02-18 so you get no match. Replacing the above query-snippet with the following would correct this particular problem.

```
inner join leave_dates i1
  on i1.date_id = g.from_date_id
inner join leave_dates i2
  on i2.date_id = g.to_date_id
inner join leave_dates i3
  on i3.date_id = g.applied_dates_id
```